# Cannot create login in stored procedure with EXECUTE AS OWNER?

Tags: sql-server, impersonation, sql-server-2014

Running `SQL Server 2014 Express`. Logged on as `sa` I try to execute the code below. It gives me the following error:

> Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Line 25 User does not have permission to
>   perform this action.

**Why?!** If I select `SYSTEM_USER` inside the procedure, it is indeed `sa` (the rightful owner).

```
USE [MyDatabase]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[create_login]
    @Login [nvarchar](256),
    @Password [nvarchar](128)
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(4000)

    SET @sql = N'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(@Login) + N' WITH PASSWORD = '
        + QUOTENAME(@Password, N'''') + N',CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=ON;'
    EXEC (@sql)
END
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[create_login] TO [my_simple_role]
GO

-- Let's go!
EXEC [dbo].[create_login] N'NewUser', N'c0Mpl3xP@55w0rd'
GO

-- Error! :(
```

If I run the statements *outside* the stored procedure, it works.

I'm trying to make a stored procedure that allows regular users to add server logins. The above does not seem to work. Please advise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A login is a server level object and therefore requires server level permissions.  `EXECUTE AS <database-user>` is a database-scoped security context.

One way to grant normal users privileged operations via stored procedures is by signing the module with a certificate that maps to a login that has the necessary rights.  The necessary steps in this case are:

1. Create a certificate in the master database
2. Create a login for that certificate
3. Grant the certificate login rights to create logins
4. Export the certificate from master
5. Import the certificate into the application database
6. Sign the stored procedure with the certificate

Below is an example gleaned from [Erland Sommarskog's web site](https://www.google.com/#q=sql+server+grant+create+login+certificate).  Note that you will need to resign the proc with the cert each time it is altered.

```
--create database master key, if necessary
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.symmetric_keys WHERE name = N'##MS_DatabaseMasterKey##')
BEGIN
    CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD='M@sterkEEPassw0rd';
END;
GO

CREATE CERTIFICATE SecurityAdministratorCertificate
   WITH
     SUBJECT = 'Allows non-privileged users to create and alter logins'
   , START_DATE = '20020101'
   , EXPIRY_DATE = '20300101';
GO

CREATE LOGIN SecurityAdministratorCertificateLogin
    FROM CERTIFICATE SecurityAdministratorCertificate;
GO
GRANT ALTER ANY LOGIN TO SecurityAdministratorCertificateLogin;
GO

--export cert from master
DECLARE @CERTENC VARBINARY(MAX);
DECLARE @CERTPVK VARBINARY(MAX);
SELECT @CERTENC = CERTENCODED(CERT_ID(N'SecurityAdministratorCertificate'));
SELECT @CERTPVK = CERTPRIVATEKEY(CERT_ID(N'SecurityAdministratorCertificate'),
       'All you need is love');

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX);
SELECT @sql = N'CREATE CERTIFICATE SecurityAdministratorCertificate FROM BINARY = '
    + CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), @CERTENC, 1)
    + ' WITH PRIVATE KEY ( BINARY = '
    + CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), @CERTPVK, 1)
    + ', DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ''All you need is love'');'

--import cert into app databases
USE MyDatabase;

--create database master key, if necessary
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.symmetric_keys WHERE name = N'##MS_DatabaseMasterKey##')
BEGIN
    CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD='M@sterkEEPassw0rd';
END;

EXEC(@sql);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[create_login]
    @Login [nvarchar](256),
    @Password [nvarchar](128)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(4000);

    SET @sql = N'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(@Login) + N' WITH PASSWORD = '
        + QUOTENAME(@Password, N'''') + N',CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=ON;';

    EXEC (@sql);

END
GO

--grant exec permissions to users
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[create_login] TO [my_simple_role];
GO 

--sign proc with certificate
ADD SIGNATURE TO dbo.create_login BY CERTIFICATE SecurityAdministratorCertificate;
GO
```

**EDIT:**

The above example encrypts the certificate private key using the database master key rather than a certificate-specific password.  In a scenario where the database is restored or attached to a different SQL instance (without also restoring the master database), you'll need to recreate server level
objects in the master database, including all logins needed by the application and certificates stored in master.  To recover the certificate, one method is to copy the cert from the user database to master after the restore/attach and then recreate the certificate login with permissions.  The DMK cannot be opened automatically in this case because the service master key, which encrypts the database master key, is different on the new instance.  The original password is needed to open the DMK manually in the script that copies the cert into the master database.  The certificate password used to copy the cert between databases is temporary and need not be retained.

Here's and example to recreate the cert and cert login in master after a restore or attach:

```
USE MyDatabase;
--open DMK with original password
OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD='M@sterkEEPassw0rd';
--export cert from user database
USE MyDatabase;
DECLARE @CERTENC VARBINARY(MAX);
DECLARE @CERTPVK VARBINARY(MAX);
SELECT @CERTENC = CERTENCODED(CERT_ID(N'SecurityAdministratorCertificate'));
SELECT @CERTPVK = CERTPRIVATEKEY(CERT_ID(N'SecurityAdministratorCertificate'),
       'temporary password here');

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX);
SELECT @sql = N'CREATE CERTIFICATE SecurityAdministratorCertificate FROM BINARY = '
    + CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), @CERTENC, 1)
    + ' WITH PRIVATE KEY ( BINARY = '
    + CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), @CERTPVK, 1)
    + ', DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ''temporary password here'');'
SELECT @sql
CLOSE MASTER KEY;

--import cert into master
USE master;

--create database master key in new instance master database, if necessary
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.symmetric_keys WHERE name = N'##MS_DatabaseMasterKey##')
BEGIN
    CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD='M@sterkEEPassw0rd';
END;

EXEC(@sql);
GO

--recreate login and assign permissions
CREATE LOGIN SecurityAdministratorCertificateLogin
    FROM CERTIFICATE SecurityAdministratorCertificate;
GRANT ALTER ANY LOGIN TO SecurityAdministratorCertificateLogin;
GO
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks! Which of these two passwords need to be stored "in a safe place" for future use? Can I, during database creation, create two random, strong, temporary passwords just in order to get the above `create_login` stored procedure working?

Comment: @l33t, the password used to export/import the cert is temporary and can be random.  The database master key password should be retained for use when the database is restored or attached to another SQL instance.
I'll add some additional info to my answer to explain in more detail.